# Force registering when buying specific products on WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a wordpress site with woocommerce store, and I want to force users to register when purchasing specific products only.
How can I do it? 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the code for your query.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_validation' , 'restict_registration_for_some_products', 10, 2 );
function restict_registration_for_some_products( $data, $errors ) {

    if( isset( $data['createaccount'] ) && !$data['createaccount'] ) {

        $retricted_ids = get_resticted_product_ids();

        if( isset( $retricted_ids ) && $retricted_ids != null ) {

            $cart_content = WC()->cart->get_cart_contents();

            $cart_ids = wp_list_pluck( $cart_content, 'product_id' );
            $cart_ids = array_values( $cart_ids );
            $common_ids = array_intersect( $retricted_ids, $cart_ids );

            if( isset( $common_ids ) && $common_ids != null ) {
                $errors->add( 'account_registration', __( 'You are not allowed to purchase these products without creating an account.', 'text-domain' ) );
            }
        }
    }
}
function get_resticted_product_ids() {
    //specific product ids
    return array(110,96,70);
}
```

Comment: Thanx, but I need to force users to sign up only when buying specific products or category. Not forcing registration for any product.

Comment: Hello, i have edited my answer, i have tested this code and is working perfectily.

Comment: Where do I enter the product IDs?

Comment: I have made a function named get_restricted_product_ids and have shown some example ids. You can write those ids in the array.

Comment: Great! Thank you so much